# Android Development in Python Realistic

Tags: android, python, user-interface

I've looked over stackoverflow and seen a variety of questions regarding python development for android.  What are the limitations?  I know I cant use a few of the UI methods.  But are there other real limitations to it?

Also do you guys have any resources for python development?

Comment: I have a similar question, I'd like to hear some feedback.

Comment: Take a look at [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) project .

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Python for Android](https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/) in the past. It's a full fledged Python implementation. You can import modules and everything